# Recycling bitmap after set to ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap

This is my code

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(bitmap != null) {
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        if(bar != null) 
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // ERROR HERE
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
    else
        Log.e(TAG,"Bitmap returned null");
}
```

Basically, I'm fetching a bitmap on `doInBackground` from the internet, and decode it to a `Bitmap`. Then, after setting it to an `ImageView` I want to know if I should call `recycle()` method.  If i call it, no image is loaded, and I get a console error log saying "Cannot generate texture from bitmap".

If I should call it then how do I do that?

Comment: what is your android version? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: I think typically, you would only recycle the bitmap early if you need to free up memory in order to do something else.  Or set your bitmap to a weak reference instead.  I don't use the recycle option frequently.

Answer (score 3):

No. Don't recycle it. Your `ImageView` is still using it.